# Appending $model->errors() array in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, codeigniter-4

I have form to submit fields a table. This table have model that I set `validationRules`. But there are some condition where I need 1 field required/mandatory occasionally. So, I'm not put this tentative required field on `validationRules`.

How to append new error item when we call $model->errors(). I tried with push new item, but existing $model->errors() always replaced with item I wanna append.

So kind like this:

```
...
$data = [
   'name' => 'Jane Doe',
   'address' => 'California',
   'gender' => 'Female',
   'hobby' => 'Reading novel',
   'book_genre' => 'Thriller'
];

if( $model->insert($data) ) {
   $response = [
      'success' => true,
      'msg' => 'Good job'
   ];
} else {

   $errors = $model->errors();

   if($this->request->getPost('hobby') == 'Reading novel' && $this->request->getPost('book_genre') == '') {
      $errors['book_genre'] = 'Book genre must be filled.';
   }
   
   $response = [
      'success' => false,
      'msg' => '<p>' . implode('</p><p>', $errors) . '</p>'
   ];
}
...
```

The point is, how to append/push new item on $model->errors(). is it possible? Why its replaced not appended.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create your condition when the field is mandatory, for example

```
if(condition){

    $this->model->setValidationRule('your field', 'your rules');

}
```

When the condition is met, the rule for that field is added, otherwise it is not

Now in the error array you will also have this if the condition is met

Obviously put the check before checking the fields with the validation

```
if(condition){
    
    $this->model->setValidationRule('your field', 'your rules');
    
}

if( $model->insert($data) ) {
    ...
```